# JavaScript and other language that use losely defined vars

Tags: javascript, variables

Hey anyone out there that uses JavaScript in a professional environment. I wanted to know the standard when comparing values using == and === operators. I was watching a video the explained that if you compared a sting with a value of '5' and an int with a value of 5 it returns true using the == operator. They then suggested to use the === for everything. I know this is wrong because what if you wanted to compare some value nested in some polymorphic objects with different type defs say one being a student and the other being an instructor the === would always return false.

After much thought I came to the conclusion that it might be best to use === whenever possible and the == when only necessary.

Can you give me some insight on what the rule of thumb is in a professional environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is simple:

Always use `===` and `!==` unless you explicitly WANT a type conversion to be allowed and have thought through the consequences of that type conversion.  In otherwords, you should be using `===` and `!==` nearly all the time.

---

Your exception for polymorphic objects does not apply because `==` and `===` both require two objects to be the exact same object when comparing two objects.  There are no type conversions in that case.  If you were comparing two properties of polymorphic objects, then only the type of the property is looked at, not the type of the containing object.

---

For detailed rules on type conversions with `==`, see this http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3.  There are some odd ones like this:

```
var x;              // x is undefined
alert(x == null);​   // alerts true
```

Comment: @DanielHaro - Read the last sentence of the paragraph that starts with `Your exception` in my answer.  It addresses that issue.

Comment: Ok, never mind I got it, if only comparing a properity the containing object would be ignored anyway, sorry I get it now I was not thinking stright. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Check out  http://jshint.com which helps enforce these best practices. They (and everyone else pretty much) recommend using `===`.

I can rarely think of a reason to use `==` over `===`.

Here's a fancy example of using `===` even when `==` might feel easier.

```
var person = {
    name: "Cody",
    age: "44"
}

var targetAge = 40;

// explicit type conversion, no wonder what's happening
if (parseInt(person.age, 10) === targetAge) {
    alert("You won!")
} else {
    alert("Sorry You Lost!");
}
```

See Also: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CFsQFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742&ei=Ze4zULqKE-aIiAKrm4HIDQ&usg=AFQjCNE3W3qcv768n0-H0LtIEf9laimwcA&sig2=NGT6Gambm-Kbk8_wAKuwTg) and [Maintainable JavaScript](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CF8QFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/Maintainable-JavaScript-Nicholas-C-Zakas/dp/1449327680&ei=ge4zUPqmFuioiAKdsYDoAg&usg=AFQjCNEfqA_-tOi0qp3I-AGhQhxn4oSXGg&sig2=ZahGhMQVsRbouT5dljHteA), which also recommend the practice.

Answer (score 0):

it's commonly used in this type of statements:

```
var x = 0;
if(x == false) {
   // this will be executed   
}
if(x === false) {
   // this not
}
if(false == '') {
  // this will be executed
}
if(false === '') {
  // this not
}
```

another example - function which is returning `FALSE` on error or `string` on success

```
function foo(bar) {
   // magic
   return ''; // this is SUCCESS
}
var result = foo(123);
if(result === false) {
  // omg error!!
}else{
  // some string returned, event empty one is OK
}
```

to be honest it's really rare to use `===` in statements